# Go lang - Bulk push the struct which is inside the array to Redis

Tags: arrays, go, struct, redis

I am working on small application, i want to bulk push the struct data
 which inside the array in single command without iterating the array of struct into the redis queue

Example struct:

```
[{abc def ghi} {jkl mno pqr}]
```

from this struct i want to insert data in redis like below

```
1) {abc def ghi}
2) {abc def ghi}
```

I am using the go lang redis client 
https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/go-redis/redis@v6.15.9+incompatible#Client.LPush

i tried inserting by Marshaling the data but it inserted as whole array of struct instead of single struct like Example struct mentioned above

example code

```
func insertredis(data) {
   datatoinsert, err := json.Marshal(data)
   LPush("key", datatoinsert)
}
```

Can anyone help to bulk push the array of struct to redis